# How to prevent double tap (bug?) on Android JB WebView?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-webview

I'm trying to port a Flash based game to Android.

I've ported it successfully (WebView), but now, the problem is that when I do a short click (short tap) somewhere in the game, it does 2 clicks (double tap), and when I do a long click (long tap) it does a short click (short tap).This is really annoying, specially when it does double fire instead of one fire. I've tried with the touch screen and a mouse; both had the same issue, so the input isn't the problem.

After reading a lot of stuff I think it must be a bug(?) on Andriod (4.x+ I think) WebView.

I hope you can help me to invert those things or to prevent those double taps as soon as possible.

Here is the code of the MainActivity.java:

```
package usr.sh.raul.dofus;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;

import android.graphics.Color;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebView;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    WebView mWebView;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @SuppressLint("SdCardPath")
    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {       
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); 
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY); 
        mWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///sdcard/Android/data/usr.sh.raul.dofus/data/loader.swf");
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: how do you expect us to help if you don't post any code?